# How can I add more statements in IF condition in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

The documentation of `IF` suggests as below

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

How can I add more statements after `THEN` and assign more than one alias to them? For example:

```
IF Market="UK" 
THEN 
SUM(Order) AS Order, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
END IF
```

Is this the correct way to do so? Or if there is any other way please share your comments

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the complete query.  `IF` is a statement does not work as a statement (although `IF()` as a function does).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Where did you read it was a query, maybe he's creating a procedure or a trigger in which case the `IF` is valid.

Comment: Put some more codes you have. Its ambiguous. What is `Market`? What is `Order`? Are they both columns or variables or params?

Comment: @Daan . . . Seems unlikely, with code such as `SUM()` and a comma separated list of columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree it's the more likely choice but you'll never know.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok you can take it as IF(). Can you give me one example to have two statement with same alias. Have you got the point?

Comment: Stored procedure WHILE? Otherwise inefficient multiple IFs with the same 'Market="UK"' conditions.